# Switch fragment1 to fragment2

Tags: android, android-fragments

Hi guys I have a fragment with a button. I want open fragment2 when button is clicked.
what is the best solution?
Can you make an example for this?
in XML fragment1:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="116dp"
        android:background="#0000"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/autobus"
        android:onClick="OPENFRAGMENT"
        android:text="ooo" />
```

in fragment1:

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

     View info = inflater.inflate(R.layout.info, container, false);

    return info;
}

public void OPENFRAGMENT(View view) 
{

}
```

in fragment2:

```
public class Fragment2 extends Fragment{

 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

         View frag = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag2, container, false);
         return frag;
 }
}
```

MainActivity:

```
 public class MainActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity  {


    ViewPager Tab;
    TabPagerAdapter TabAdapter;
    ActionBar actionBar;
    public boolean StatusConnection = false;
    public int thread = 0;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 


        TabAdapter = new TabPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()); 
        Tab = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager); 
        Tab.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                        actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(
                                position);
                        Tab.setCurrentItem(position);
                    }

                });
        Tab.setAdapter(TabAdapter); 

        actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        ActionBar.TabListener tabListener = new ActionBar.TabListener(){

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab arg0,FragmentTransaction arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab arg0,FragmentTransaction arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Tab.setCurrentItem(arg0.getPosition());
            }
            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab arg0,FragmentTransaction arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        }; 

        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("A").setTabListener(tabListener));
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("B").setTabListener(tabListener));
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("C").setTabListener(tabListener));

 @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
        switch (i) {
            case 0:
                return new Info();
            case 1:
                return new B(); 
            case 2:
                return  new  C();
```

activity_main.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/pager"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first you must get view from the button on your 1st fragment, using this code:

```
btnChFrag = info.findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

(info is the view of your fragment layout)

then you need to set onclicklistener on that button

```
btnChFrag.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Fragment2 newFragment = new Fragment2();
        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction(); 
        ft.replace(R.id.container, newFragment); 
        ft.commit();
}
```

change R.id.container with your container on your MainActivity view

so your code on fragment1 will be:

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {

private Button btnChFrag 

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View info = inflater.inflate(R.layout.info, container, false);
    btnChFrag = info.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    //set button onclicklistener here

    return info;
}
```

-----Edit------

sorry I totally forgot you want to do it with button, my bad

this is the code of fragment1

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View info = inflater.inflate(R.layout.info, container, false);


    Button btn1 = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.button1);

    btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ((MainActivity)Fragment1.this.getActivity()).Tab.setCurrentItem(2);
        }
    });
    return info;
}
```

tried it, and it works :)

Comment: Hi i have added MainActivity on 1st post but i get a error with container -                  ft.replace(R.id.container, newFragment); 
change R.id.container with your container on your MainActivity view

.  What's!?

Comment: @roxdragon if you use a fragment, you will have an Activity running by default (the one who call your fragment1) and it will always have a container in the xml, that will replaced with the fragment you want to change. Or you can add your activity code and xml on your question, maybe i can help you further

Comment: what code do you use in your MainActivity to put the fragment1 to your activity? is it using FragmentManager or else? And also, did you really need the viewpager?

Comment: so u using setpager with an adapter, I think you should set the page in the adapter, not in the fragment. if you extends FragmentPagerAdapter in your TabPagerAdapter Class, it should have getItem method, you should add fragment there i think

Comment: ok, maybe you can add your TabPagerAdapter class, so I can try it for you

Comment: Yes thank you, this work for me... i have edited 1st post in mainactivity... but i want when i click the button open a new fragment not in wievpager
Thank you in advance

Comment: lol yeah, sorry, my bad for that.. i forgot you want to do it with button.. check my edited answer again..

Comment: ((MainActivity)Fragment1.this.getActivity()).Tab.setCurrentItem(2);
 sorry, but Fragment2 is not in Tab... Fragment2 is created but don't use this in tab. Edited Mainactivity... Info - A - B. Fragment2 isn't in tabs :)